# How to import std::less<T> as a typename?

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I have the following code in Sol.h with most omitted due to school rules:

```
template <typename T,int promote = 1, typename compare = std::less<T>() >
class Sol{
private:
  struct node{
    T data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
  };
node *head, *tail;
public:
  typedef unsigned int size_type;
  typedef T key_type;
  typedef T value_type;
  size_type count;
  Sol() : head(0), tail(0) {
    count=0;
  }
```

Basicly it is a container similar to vector but it does some things that we are required to template. I can't seem to get the "typename compare = std::less< T>" -ignore the space.

When I compile with the test code I get two errors from Sol.h and the rest all relate to them.

```
>temple> g++ -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic Sol.h main.cc
Sol.h:6:61: error: expected type-specifier
Sol.h:6:61: error: expected '>'
main.cc: In function 'int main()':
main.cc:19:19: error: template argument 3 is invalid
main.cc:19:24: error: invalid type in declaration before '(' token
main.cc:19:48: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
main.cc:19:48: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
main.cc:19:48: error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
main.cc:20:19: error: template argument 3 is invalid
main.cc:20:31: error: expected initializer before 'it'
main.cc:22:13: error: request for member 'erase' in 'foo', which is of non-class type 'int'
main.cc:24:9: error: 'it' was not declared in this scope
main.cc:24:18: error: request for member 'find' in 'foo', which is of non-class type 'int'
main.cc:25:9: error: request for member 'end' in 'foo', which is of non-class type 'int'
main.cc:28:13: error: request for member 'find' in 'foo', which is of non-class type 'int'
main.cc:30:13: error: request for member 'find' in 'foo', which is of non-class type 'int'
main.cc: In function 'std::string cat(const T&) [with T = int, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]':
main.cc:23:24:   instantiated from here
main.cc:12:35: error: 'int' is not a class, struct, or union type
main.cc:12:50: error: request for member 'end' in 'con', which is of non-class type 'const int'
main.cc:12:35: error: 'int' is not a class, struct, or union type
main.cc:12:35: error: 'int' is not a class, struct, or union type
main.cc:12:35: error: 'int' is not a class, struct, or union type
```

To be clear line 6 is the template line.

Comment: Hint: What is the return type of the compare argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
typename compare = std::less<T>()
```

To

```
typename compare = std::less<T>
```

You're wanting a type, not an object.

Also you have to do `#include <functional>` because that's where `std::less` is defined.

Comment: I have tried that. Same results. And the weird part is that I asked classmates about it and they have managed to get the same code to compile even though we are using university machines with the same compilers.

Comment: @TylerScott same error or another? And trust me though, that is really an error in the code. Whether there are other errors or not. Also make sure you're really changing it (e.g. make sure you are saving the file, etc.)

Comment: I checked to make sure it was saving and it was. I will update the error to include the whole command and error stack.

Comment: Also I can show you all the code through email so long as you aren't a student at CSU.

Comment: @TylerScott actually no I was wrong, you have to `#include <functional>` which is where `std::less` is. So both remove those `()` and do `#include <functional>` above the definition.